# How to send AJAX Request only if store size is 0

Tags: extjs

How to send AJAX request for combo box by having condition that current store size is 0.

Basically I have two remote combo box which are cascaded and both are lazily loaded ( This behaviour cannot be changed)

I found even if the second combo box is cascaded based on events in first combobox upoun expansion it makes AJAX call to server ( Only first expansion though)

querymode local and autoload option will not work as it load the combo box on page load when store is created.

Given below is code snippet.

```
  xtype: 'combo',id='firstcombo', name: 'DEFAULT_VALUE' ,minChars:2, value: decodeHtmlContent('') ,width:200 ,listWidth:500, resizable: true,
 valueField : 'id', displayField: 'id', pageSize: 15,forceSelection:true, enableKeyEvents: true,
 store: new Ext.data.Store({reader: new Ext.data.CFQueryReader({id: 'NAME', 
            fields:[{name:'id', mapping:'id'}]}), 
            fields: [{name:'id', mapping:'id'}], 
            url:'server/ajax/Params'
            }

 }),
 listeners : {
         select:function(combo, record, index) {
            this.setRawValue(decodeHtmlContent(record.get('id')));
            cascadeFields();
        }



 xtype: 'combo',id='secondcombo', name: 'DEFAULT_VALUE' ,minChars:2, value: decodeHtmlContent('') ,width:200 ,listWidth:500, resizable: true,
 valueField : 'id', displayField: 'id', pageSize: 15,forceSelection:true, enableKeyEvents: true,
 store: new Ext.data.Store({reader: new Ext.data.CFQueryReader({id: 'NAME', 
            fields:[{name:'id', mapping:'id'}]}), 
            fields: [{name:'id', mapping:'id'}], 
            url:'server/ajax/Params',
            baseParam:{valuefirst:''}
            },
            listeners: {

                beforeload: function(store, options) {
                    var value = Ext.getCmp('fistcombo').value;
                    Ext.apply(options.params, {

                                valuefirst:value
                            });


                }, 

 }),
 listeners : {
         select:function(combo, record, index) {
            this.setRawValue(decodeHtmlContent(record.get('id')));
        }


function cascadeFields()
{

  var combo = Ext.getCmp('secondcombo');

  if(combo.store)
  {

  var store = combo.store;


  combo.setDisabled(true);
  combo.clearValue('');
  combo.store.removeAll();
  combo.store.load();        
  combo.setDisabled(false);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To just extend your code you can do it Like so

```
listeners: {
    beforeload: function(store, options) {
        if (store.getCount() > 0) {
            return false; // will abort the load operation.
        }
        var value = Ext.getCmp('fistcombo').value;
        Ext.apply(options.params, {
             valuefirst:value
        });
    }
}
```

This should work all the same in ExtJS 3.x and ExtJS4.x cause you didn't specified this. But I guess you are using 3.x

If this hangs the combo give me feedback cause there is still another but a bit more complex way.

Comment: I posted exactly the same solution 17 seconds after you do it. +1

Comment: Here is what I have solved by this input. Basically I have two combo boxes and I was cascading second combo box based on 'select' event in other combo box. If second combo box is cascaded user should not be able to reload that combo box by refreshing or by giving direct AJAX request. This check in 'beforeLoad' method avoids that.

Comment: There's a "mark correct" button next to this guy's answer.  You should use it.  Sorry for being so Frank, but that's what sra meant for the most part if this solved your problem.